# limit of function $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{ikx}e^{-ik'x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, quantum-mechanics

I am studying Principles of Quantum Mechanics Shankar.R and on page 66 he says that there is a way to define the limit of function $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{ikx}e^{-ik'x}$ "to be the average over a large interval".

[image]

what would be the intermediate steps ? I fail to understand it completely. My attempts are that he uses the average value of function over an interval [a,b] (as in calculus) and the definition of the dirac delta function using Fourier transform. 1/Delta becomes zero as it delta goes to infinity.

Moreover i cannot find over the internet where in mathematics does someone define the limit of such functions by using average value over a large interval? Why do we do that? Can someone point me a link.

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: First, note that $e^{ikx}e^{-k'x} = e^{i(k-k')x}$

Comment: @Luis it's a typo from the book: there should be an $L$ instead of $\lambda$

Comment: Perhaps [Cesaro summability of an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation#Ces.C3.A0ro_summability_of_an_integral) is the idea he's going for

Comment: Since $$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{ikx}e^{-ik'x}=0\quad\text{if }k \ne k'$$is false in the usual mathematical sense, it seems the book wants instead to use another sense "average over a large interval".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no insight into *why* he's taking an average. However, here are two important pieces of information:

- The function we are considering here is $f(x) = e^{ikx}e^{-ik'x} = e^{i(k-k')x}$.
- To take the average value of a function $f$over $[a,b]$, we compute
  $$
  \frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
  $$

Thus, the average of **our** function over the interval $[L, L + \Delta]$ is the integral
$$
\frac{1}{\Delta} \int_L^{L + \Delta} e^{i(k-k')x}\,dx
$$
It is this value whose limit we evaluate as $L,\Delta \to \infty$.